# Export Tainted Canvas

Tags: export, openstreetmap, infragistics, raster, ignite-ui

We render vector shapes along with background map (Open street maps). But we are not able to export this raster map coming from OSM. Is there any way we can export this map. It throws error 'Tainted Canvas cannot be exported'.
Regards,
Pavan

Comment: Currently it is impossible to answer. Your question doesn't contain even the slightest information about the tools you are using.

Comment: Sorry for that. We are using infragistics IgniteUI map jquery control to plot the map using shape series. Background map is configured for OSM.

Answer (score 1):

OpenStreep Maps images come without CORS approval (Cross Origin Resource Sharing).

Documentation of CORS enabled image says:

"Although you can use images without CORS approval in your canvas, doing so taints the canvas. Once a canvas has been tainted, you can no longer pull data back out of the canvas. For example, you can no longer use the canvas toBlob(), toDataURL(), or getImageData() methods; doing so will throw a security error."

You can try to use the [tilePath](https://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2017.2/ui.igMap#options:backgroundContent.tilePath) property to set an image url that points to a server that allows CORS, i.e. its Access-Control-Allow-Origin header allows the resource to be shared with a given origin.
//Initialization

```
$("#map").igMap({
backgroundContent: {
    type: "bing",
    key: "abcdefghijk123456",
    tilePath: "http://www.example.com/tiles/"
}});
```